# Getting client IP address using JSMPP

Tags: java, sockets, smpp, jsmpp

I have created an smpp server and used the JSMPP-2.3.4 library. The problem is that the InetAddress method does not return the client address but the host address unlike in Sockets. I'm trying to implement a whitelist feature and I cannot get the client address

```
InetAddress address = serverSession.getInetAddress();
String host = address.getHostAddress();
```

The host in that is 127.0.0.1 . How can I get the client IP sending a bind request to my server ?

**My current solution uses IP tables.**

Comment: Client IP is the IP address of running application?

Comment: No, it is the IP address of the application trying to access the smpp server via port 8056